# How to hide MediaPlayerElement's ProgressBar?

Tags: uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

When buffering online media, `MediaPlayerElement` always show `ProgressBar`. I want to hide it and use my own.
How? Thx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified MediaTransportControls's style, and set 
"BufferingProgressBar.Visibility" to "Collapse" when buffering.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="MediaStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Buffering">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="BufferingProgressBar.Visibility" Value="Collapse" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Loading">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="BufferingProgressBar.Visibility" Value="Collapse" />
        </VisualState.Setters>

        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressSlider"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="0"
                Duration="0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MediaControlsCommandBar"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="0"
                Duration="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>

</VisualStateGroup>
```